# Exit 1 if there any output, otherwise 0

Tags: bash, exit-code, gnu-findutils

I have the following line on a GitHub Action:

```bash
find kubernetes-manifests -regextype egrep -regex '.*ya?ml$' -exec kubeconform "{}" \;
```

Unfortunately, `kubeconform` doesn't `return 1` or anything else on errors; it is always 0 and some message.

Is it possible to catch the output, check if it is empty, and if it is empty, `exit 0`; otherwise, echo the output and `exit 1`?

Comment: The usage examples in the documentation (https://github.com/yannh/kubeconform#Usage-examples) show the `kubeconform` binary exiting with 1 when validating an invalid manifest and exiting with 0 when validating a valid manifest.

Comment: Maybe OP's problem is that `find` does not forward the exit status of `-exec ... {} \;`. Try `-exec ... {} +` or `-quit`.

Comment: @j_b, then why my GitHub action is passing when I have an invalid YAML? Is it because I'm using it on a find/exec?

Comment: Switch to `xargs` or this might help: [How to get the exit code of commands started by find?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392970/74329)

Comment: Instead of `find` or `xargs` bash built-ins should be sufficient: `shopt -s nullglob globstar; kubeconform **/*yaml **/*yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch from `\;` to `+` to preserve exit code of `kubeconform`.